# Change Type dynamically in Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically change the {{type}} but it isn't happening. It has options such as info, success, warning and danger. I want it to change as the profile_percent increases.

The profile_percent increases but the colour remain the same :(

Where do you think I'm going wrong?

```
    <progressbar class="progress-striped" value="user.profile_percent" type="{{type}}">{{user.profile_percent}}%</progressbar>
```

Documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar

Comment: Can you share your controller code with us (javascript where you defined your type model)?

Comment: I don't have any controller written for this. I don't know how to write a controller for this. The documentation has a controller written to show "randomly". I can't figure out how to go about it myself though.

Comment: Looking into the github code it should work. You will have to show us your code.

Comment: That is my code. The color just doesn't change :(

Anyways, my angular guy will be back tomorrow. Will get him to fix it. Thank You for time.